# How to retrieve the code of a selected module from a checkbox?

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I want to be able, through a list of modules with checkboxes, to retrieve the code of the selected module and submit it.

**The Code:**

```java
@GetMapping("/add/{etudiant}/{section}")
public String afficherPageInscription(@PathVariable("etudiant") Integer etudiantId,
  @PathVariable("section") String section, Model model) {
  model.addAttribute("etudiantId", etudiantId);
  model.addAttribute("moduleDto", new Module());

  List < Module > modules = moduleService.getModulesIns();
  model.addAttribute("modules", modules);

  return "inscription/addInscription";
}

@PostMapping("/add/{etudiant}/{section}")
public String soumettreFormulaireInscription(
  @PathVariable("etudiant") Integer etudiantId,
  @PathVariable("section") String section,
  Model model) {

  if (modulesSelectionnes != null && !modulesSelectionnes.isEmpty()) {
    // Faites quelque chose avec les modules sélectionnés
    for (String moduleCode: modulesSelectionnes) {
      // Exemple : enregistrez chaque module sélectionné dans la base de données
      moduleService.addInscription(moduleCode, etudiantId);
    }

    // Autres opérations, si nécessaire

    return "redirect:/module/liste"; // Redirection après traitement
  } else {
    // Aucun module sélectionné, gestion d'erreur ou autre traitement
    model.addAttribute("erreur", "Veuillez sélectionner au moins un module.");
    return "redirect:/erreur"; // Redirection vers le formulaire avec un message d'erreur
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking for. Do you want to know which checkboxes have been checked when sending a form to the server? What problems do yo face apart from an implied "I don't know what to do"?

Comment: I would like to be able to add existing modules to a student via checkboxes and a submit button. I am able to retrieve the list of modules for which the student is not yet enrolled, but in the POST, I would like to save the selected module to the database once it is selected.

Comment: <td>
            <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{modulesSelectionnes}" th:name="modulesSelectionnes"
                   th:value="${module.code}" />
        </td>

Comment: Ok, so you're basically creating a list of checkboxes with the same name and different values. Now where's the problem? Aren't they sent to the server as expected? Don't you know how to extract the selections? Don't you know how to add the new modules to a student on the server?

Comment: yes , all your question is correct

Comment: Aren't they sent to the server as expected? Don't you know how to extract the selections? Don't you know how to add the new modules to a student on the server? YES

Comment: This might be a little to broad then our you still might need to elaborate on this, e.g. where you're sending the form that contains the checkboxes etc. [Multiple checkboxes with the same name should be sent as an array that contains the values of the checked ones](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox#handling_multiple_checkboxes) so I'd start there and check if that works (e.g. by getting the request object on the server side and checking the values).